# log4j2 errors causing Tomcat stop

Tags: tomcat, log4j2

HI I am using Tomcat 7 with Java 1.7. On Eclipse, I tried to start the tomcat and got the following errors. Any direction for me to fix the following error? Thanks

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
> Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that
> were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs
> during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. Aug
> 20, 2021 5:57:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
> Aug 20, 2021 5:57:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
> listenerStart SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
> org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener  at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4933)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
> configuration: logging only errors to the console. Aug 20, 2021
> 5:57:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
> SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous
> error(s) Aug 20, 2021 5:57:32 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: One or
> more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
> appropriate container log file Aug 20, 2021 5:57:32 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
> [/sbmvnooe] startup failed due to previous errors Aug 20, 2021 5:57:32
> PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
> ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Comment: You must have declared the `org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener` listener in your `web.xml`, but you didn't add [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web/2.14.1) and its dependencies to your application. BTW: On Tomcat 7 you don't need to use the `Log4jServletContextListener` at all, since `log4j-web` uses the [pluggability features](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#pluggability) introduced in Servlet 3.0.

Comment: thank you. does it mean that I did not import the right  classes in   Java files?

Comment: It means that the resulting WAR file does not have all required libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`. How to correct it depends on how you build your project (Maven, Ant, ...). In Eclipse you need to add the Log4j libraries to _"Properties > Deployment assembly"_.

Comment: Thank you. Very strangely. I cleaned the project. And I could export the war but I could not start the tomcat on the eclipse owing to the above error. Any idea?